# What should I use to lubricate the flaps that controls the temperature and which vents the air comes out of?

Tags: ac, hvac, lubrication, saab, vents

The [control shafts](http://www.neobrothers.co.uk/used-heater-control-shaft-genuine-saab-ng900-p-1624.html?osCsid=b51qa7kgmh92mpvhjsqev75su5)  that move the flaps which control the the hot/cold air and which vents the air come out have broken.  The car is a 1999 93 Saab so I'm assuming that the hinges  (the flap has a peg that goes through a hole) just need lubrication. (In addition to a replacement control shaft).

I can see that there's existing grease of some sort.

What should I be using?  Is it something special and what is it called?

Comment: Are you refering to the dash outlets or the divetrer that controls heat/defrost/dash fuunctions also called a mixing door?

Comment: I'm referring to both actually. There's two control shafts and they're both broken. (the design of the control shafts is inherently weak).  I've only looked at the side that controls the dash outlets from when it previously broke.  I'm making an assumption the mixing door is similar.  Itls a pain to open up the paneling so wanted to be be prepared with the lub before I took everything apart again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In lieu of a better (more specialized) answer, I would use high temperature grease. Nothing too expensive though, I doubt those hinges get hotter than 500F.